# string.charAt(x) or string[x]?

Tags: javascript, string

Is there any reason I should use `string.charAt(x)` instead of the bracket notation `string[x]`?

Comment: *Word of caution*: using either syntax for emojis or any other unicode characters past the [Basic Multilingual Plane BPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (AKA [the "Astral Plane"](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-unicode-characters-outside-the-BMP-called-astral)) `"".charAt(0)` will return an unusable character

Comment: @KyleMit `""[0]` also returns an unusable character.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - right - hence *using **either** syntax for emojis... will return an unusable character*.

Comment: @KyleMit (and other readers): That’s why `Array.from("")[0]` or `[...""][0]` should be used in this case. This still won’t work for more complex grapheme clusters, but TC39 proposals exist to simplify this.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Bracket notation now works on all major browsers, except for IE7 and below.

```
// Bracket Notation
"Test String1"[6]

// charAt Implementation
"Test String1".charAt(6)
```

**It used to be a bad idea to use brackets, for these reasons ([Source](http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/dangerous-bracket-notation-for-strings.html)):**

> **This notation does not work in IE7.**
>   The first code snippet will return
>   undefined in IE7. If you happen to use
>   the bracket notation for strings all
>   over your code and you want to migrate
>   to `.charAt(pos)`, this is a real pain:
>   Brackets are used all over your code
>   and there's no easy way to detect if
>   that's for a string or an
>   array/object.
>
> **You can't set the character using this notation.** As there is no warning of
>   any kind, this is really confusing and
>   frustrating. If you were using the
>   `.charAt(pos)` function, you would not
>   have been tempted to do it.

Comment: True, the notation does not work in IE7, but that's not a huge disadvantage nowadays. Meanwhile, benchmarks I did showed a three time decrease in performance when using charAt vs indexer in Chrome when the string is boxed in an object. I know that's not really relevant, but still worth noting.https://jsfiddle.net/mdasxxd2/

Comment: A more accurate test (benchmark.js) https://esbench.com/bench/579609a0db965b9a00965b9e

Comment: Despite being the highest-scored this answer is now (2019) significantly out of date. [The answer below quoting MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943807/3358139) should be referred to instead.

Comment: [No significant performance difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHtX6.png) on Chrome 89 in 2021.

Answer (score 131):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access):

> There are two ways to access an individual character in a string. The first is the [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) method, part of ECMAScript 3:
>
> ```
> return 'cat'.charAt(1); // returns "a"
> ```
>
> The other way is to treat the string as an array-like object, where each individual characters correspond to a numerical index. This has been supported by most browsers since their first version, except for IE. It was standardised in ECMAScript 5:
>
> ```
> return 'cat'[1]; // returns "a"
> ```
>
> **The second way requires ECMAScript 5 support (and not supported in some older browsers).**
>
> In both cases, attempting to change an individual character won't work, as strings are immutable, i.e., their properties are neither neither "writable" nor "configurable".

- `str.charAt(i)` is better from a compatibility perspective if IE6/IE7 compatibility is required.
- `str[i]` is more modern and works in IE8+ and all other browsers (all Edge/Firefox/Chrome, Safari 2+, all iOS/Android).

Comment: True, ECMA 5 is not yet supported on ALL browsers, but it IS supported on MOST browsers: meaning IE9 and above and all Chrome/Firefox versions:

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Property_access_on_strings

No JS feature will ever be 100% supported, and I feel that avoiding the use of ECMA 5 features will leave us in the past forever...

Answer (score 118):

They can give different results in edge cases.

```
'hello'[NaN] // undefined
'hello'.charAt(NaN) // 'h'

'hello'[true] //undefined
'hello'.charAt(true) // 'e'
```

The charAt function depends on how the index is converted to a Number in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3).

Comment: Also `'hello'[undefined] // undefined` and `'hello'.charAt(undefined) //h`

Comment: `null` works like `undefined`, but see this: `"hello"["00"] // undefined` but `"hello".charAt("00") // "h"` and `"hello"["0"] // "h"`

Comment: This wholeheartedly convinces me to keep using `[]`.

Comment: This also means that `.charAt()` performs an extra conversion for its parameter into a `Number`. FYI, there's almost no performance difference nowadays.

Comment: This answer should move up, it actually explains that there is a difference between the 2 methods. The other answers talk about compatibility for IE7 (I mean really?) while this answer explains a very real pitfall.

Comment: Also `"hello"[313]` is `undefined` and `"hello".charAt(313)` is `""`.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why `"hello".charAt(NaN)` is `'h'`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9980608/4284627).

Comment: To summarize, `NaN` is coerced to `false` aka `0`, `true` is coerced to `1`

Answer (score 26):

There is a difference when you try to access an index which is out of bounds or not an integer.

`string[x]` returns the character at the `x`th position in `string` if `x` is an integer between 0 and `string.length-1`, and returns `undefined` otherwise.

`string.charAt(x)` converts `x` to an integer using the process explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980660/4284627) (which basically rounds `x` down if `x` is a non-integer number and returns 0 if `parseInt(x)` is `NaN`) and then returns the character at the that position if the integer  is between 0 and `string.length-1`, and returns an empty string otherwise.

Here are some examples:

```
"Hello"[313]    //undefined
"Hello".charAt(313)    //"", 313 is out of bounds

"Hello"[3.14]    //undefined
"Hello".charAt(3.14)    //'l', rounds 3.14 down to 3

"Hello"[true]    //undefined
"Hello".charAt(true)    //'e', converts true to the integer 1

"Hello"["World"]    //undefined
"Hello".charAt("World")    //'H', "World" evaluates to NaN, which gets converted to 0

"Hello"[Infinity]    //undefined
"Hello".charAt(Infinity)    //"", Infinity is out of bounds
```

Another difference is that assigning to `string[x]` does nothing (which can be confusing) and assigning to `string.charAt(x)` is an error (as expected):

```
var str = "Hello";
str[0] = 'Y';
console.log(str);    //Still "Hello", the above assignment did nothing
str.charAt(0) = 'Y';    //Error, invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

The reason why assigning to `string[x]` doesn't work is because [Javascript strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717855/4284627).

Answer (score 11):

String.charAt() is the original standard and works in all the browsers.
In IE 8+ and other browsers, you may use bracket notation to access characters but IE 7 and below did not support it.

If somebody really wants to use bracket notation in IE 7, it's wise to convert the string to an array using `str.split('')` and then use it as an array, compatible with any browser.

```
var testString = "Hello"; 
var charArr = testString.split("");
charArr[1]; // "e"
```

Comment: IE supports bracket notation from 8 onward.

Comment: This method breaks when dealing with Unicode: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: This method would be inefficient when dealing with really large strings because it would duplicate the data in memory (the original string and the array).

Answer (score 7):

Very interesting outcome when you test the string index accessor vs the `charAt()` method. Seems Chrome is the only browser that likes `charAt` more.

[CharAt vs index 1](http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-index/2)

[ChartAt vs index 2](http://jsperf.com/array-index-vs-string-charat/2)

[ChartAt vs index 3](http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-array/3)

Comment: This is not the case anymore.  `index` is wayyy faster in chrome, too.

Answer (score 4):

#### What is the difference between using `charAt(index)` and `string[index]` to access a character?

| # | index value | charAt (return value) | Bracket notation (return value) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | index >= length | `''` | `undefined` |
| 2 | index < 0 | `''` | `undefined` |
| 3 | index: falsy | character at 0 | `undefined` |
| 4 | index = true | character at 1 | `undefined` |
| 5 | Number(index: string) === NaN | character at 0 | `undefined` |
| 6 | Number(index: string) !== NaN | character at index | character at index |
| 7 | index: decimal | character at `Math.floor(Number(index))` | `undefined` |

**Notes:**

- For **`charAt()`**, `index` is first attempted to be type coerced into a number before the index is searched.

  - Boolean values are type coerced. `Number(true)` evaluates to 1 and `Number(false)` evaluates to 0.
  - All falsy values return index 0.
  - An array containing a single element [1] or ['1'] when coerced, returns the number. Array containing multiple elements returns `NaN` and the treatment happens as per the table above.
  - If index is a decimal value, as a number, string or array with one element, `Math.floor(Number(index))` is applied.
- For **bracket notation**, type coercion is attempted when index provided is a string or an array containing one element.

  - Boolean values are not type coerced. So `true` doesn't coerce to `1`. `true` or `false` both return `undefined`.
  - All falsy values except 0, return `undefined`.
  - Decimal values return `undefined`.
- `type falsy = null | undefined | NaN | ''`

  - `falsy` doesn't include 0 here, as 0 is a valid Number index.

```
let str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

/** index > str.length */
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(27) }); // returns ''
console.log({ brackets: str[27] }); // returns undefined

/** index < 0 */
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(-2) }); // returns ''
console.log({ brackets: str[-2] }); // returns undefined

/** Falsy Values */

// All falsy values, return character at index 0
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(NaN) }); // returns 'A'
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(false) }); // returns 'A'
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(undefined) }); // returns 'A'
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(null) }); // returns 'A'
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt('') }); // returns 'A'

// All falsy values except 0, return undefined
console.log({ brackets: str[NaN] }); // returns undefined
console.log({ brackets: str[false] }); // returns undefined
console.log({ brackets: str[undefined] }); // returns undefined
console.log({ brackets: str[null] }); // returns undefined
console.log({ brackets: str[''] }); // returns undefined

/** index = Boolean(true) */
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(true) }); // returns 'B', (character at index 1)
console.log({ brackets: str[true] }); // undefined

/** Type coercion: Failure */
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt('A1') }); // returns 'A' (character at index 0)
console.log({ brackets: str['ABC'] }); // returns undefined

/** Type coercion: Success */
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt('1') }); // returns 'B' (attempts to access index after type coercion)
console.log({ brackets: str['1'] }); // returns undefined (attempts to access index after type coercion)

/** Decimal Values */
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(1.9) }); // returns 'B', applies Math.floor(Number(index))
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt('1.9') }); // returns 'B', applies Math.floor(Number(index))
console.log({ charAt: str.charAt(['1.9']) }); // returns 'B', applies Math.floor(Number(index))

console.log({ brackets: str[1.9] }); // returns undefined
```

[View my Quick Reference on Github](https://github.com/jayantasamaddar/quick-reference)