# Need Regex that check at least 4 different character in string

Tags: jquery

I need Regex that checks if a `String` has at least 4 unique characters. For example, if a string is `"test"` then it fails because it have three different chars but if a string is `"test1"` then it passes.

Comment: Do **Not** Use a "regular expression" for this. A regular expression **cannot handle this problem** well. (Yes, it's *possible*, fsvo, but it's a nightmare and limited to a relatively small upper-bound length.)

Comment: Actually, that is not regular.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how to do that with a regex, nor would I expect that to be a good way to solve the problem.  Here's a more general purpose function with regular javascript:

```
function countUniqueChars(testVal) {
    var index = {};
    var ch, cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < testVal.length; i++) {
        ch = testVal.charAt(i);
        if (!(ch in index)) {
            index[ch] = true;
            ++cnt;
        }
    }
    return(cnt);
}

function hasFourUniqueChars(testVal) {
    return(countUniqueChars(testVal) >= 4);
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bqBRv/

Comment: @ChuckNorris "Chuck Norris after dentist"

Comment: @jfriend00, What's with charAt() instead of indexing? Is it faster?

Comment: @Walkerneo - I've just gotten in the habit of using `.charAt()`.  [This other SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx) suggests there are reasons why `.charAt()` is better than array notation for a bunch of reasons, most notably that older versions of IE don't like the array notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using additional libraries, [undescore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#) provides some utility functions that can make this a very short and sweet query:

```
function countUniqueCharacters(value) {
  return _.uniq(value.split("")).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "abcdef"
var counter = 0; 
hash = new Object(); 
var i;
for(i=0; i< str.length; i++){
  if(!hash[str.charAt(i)]){
    counter +=1; hash[str.charAt(i)]=true
  }
}

if(counter < 4){
  console.log("error");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this ignore the last character?

Comment: No. last symbol of string has string.length - 1 position

Comment: But you only interate up to string.length - 2, notice the "i< string.length -1". This is part of why I dislike explicit for loops, people mess them up all the time.