# Is the charAt(i) method faster than using only [i]?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm developping a web app that deals with large strings and so I want to know which way to get a single char is faster, this one:

```
var myStr = 'foo';
return myStr[i];
```

Or this one:

```
var myStr = 'foo';
return myStr.charAt(i);
```

Comment: By the way, [here's a jsperf](http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-arraycall/2) if you wanted to know difference in performance. I think it depends on the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing characters in a string by index via bracket notation (`myStr[i]`) not only doesn't work in IE, but is not specified in the ES3 standard (the one *all* browsers implement correctly).

However, the ES5 specification (the current standard) [does include](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5) indexed characters (which are supported by modern browsers):

> The array index named properties correspond to the individual
>   characters of the String value.

Thus, to write **backwards-compatible cross-browser** code, you should access individual characters via `charAt`.

Comment: It will be a valid standard, in the future.
Of course, that means that until 2020, for sake of backwards-compatibility with non opt-in JS, you'll be using .charAt, anyway.

Comment: @Norguard, that would be cool! Could you link to the proposal/draft?

Comment: I'd love to go diving through all of ECMAScript5, Harmony and Next to find the official proclamations, but I really don't have the time -- I believe it's a standard within the strict-mode of ES5.    Here's an excerpt from the abridged versions of one of the holy grails:   http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449335977/6dot-arrays/id3191775     Otherwise, you can hear a few big names (like Crockford, and Moz people) talk about it, in talks -- of course, those talks would be from 2009-2010, probably, talking about the future, which still isn't here.

Comment: @Norguard, thanks! It's actually in ES5: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which is faster, but you might want to look at [string.charAt(x) or string[x]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx)
to see discussion on why myStr.charAt(i) is better than using myStr[i] (the answer is browser compatibility)

Comment: Well, this link is util, but as I showed in my edit, I'm acessing the var that contains the string, not it directly

Comment: Also, re:speed, this doesn't show IE, but it shows relative perfomance speeds; running the tests it appears that bracket notation is faster: http://jsperf.com/string-charat-vs-bracket-notation