# Javascript string to array(if string is without any space)

Tags: javascript

I have a string for e.g:

```
        var str = 'abcdef';
```

i want to get it in an array format e.g:

```
        var a;
        a[0]=a;
        a[1]=b;  and so on..
```

i am aware of split method but in this case of string without any space how can i split as individual character??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it like this ,

```
var str='abcdef'; 
alert(str[0]);
```

or

```
var str='abcdef'; 
alert(str.charAt(0));
```

refer following link to chose which is the best way.
http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/dangerous-bracket-notation-for-strings.html

Comment: Right, but use `str.charAt(0)`

Comment: @lan: Can you explain why. without saying just use this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx for reasons why `charAt` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Use: `str.split('')`. That will create an array with characters of `str` as elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "abcdef";
var a;
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    a.push(s.charAt(i));
}
```

or

```
 var s = "abcdef";
 var a;
 var a= s.split('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="abcdef";
var a=new Array;
for (var x=0; x<str.length; x++) {
    a[x] = str.charAt(x);
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: You should use `str.charAt(x)`, not `str[x]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:-

```
var array = str.split('');
```

Look at the following page to know more about splits.

[Javascript split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)