# JavaScript: Have we always been able to index into a string like it's an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexing

I've always thought that if you want to access the nth character in a string called `str`, then you have to do something like `str.charAt(n)`. Today I was making a little dummy test page and by mistake, I accessed it with `str[n]` and to my surprise, it returned me the nth character of the string. I threw up this little purpose built page to exhibit this unexpected (to me) behaviour:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var str = "ABCDEFGH";
        if (str[4] === str.charAt(4)) alert("strings can be indexed directly as if they're arrays");
        var str2 = new String("ABCDEFGH");
        if (str2[4] === str2.charAt(4)) alert("even if they're declared as object type String");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It wasn't always like this, was it?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx

Comment: Grrr, I did search but somehow missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that was not always possible.

If you run your code in an old enough browser, IE 7 for example, it won't be able to access the string like that. On those older engines, you'd have to use `.charAt(index)` instead.

Comment: Good to know, and makes it therefore unusable. It's charAt all the way !!

Answer (score 4):

> There are two ways to access an individual character in a string. The
>   first is the `charAt` method:
>
> ```
> return 'cat'.charAt(1); // returns "a"
> ```
>
> The other way is to treat the string as an array-like object, where
>   individual characters correspond to a numerical index:
>
> ```
> return 'cat'[1]; // returns "a"
> ```
>
> > **Array-like character access (the second way above) is not part of ECMAScript 3. It is a JavaScript and ECMAScript 5 feature.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Good to know, and makes it therefore unusable. It's charAt all the way !!

Answer (score 2):

As long as I can remember, but:

> Array-like character access [...] is not part of ECMAScript 3. It is a JavaScript and ECMAScript 5 feature.

(...and not supported in all browsers) [See here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)

Comment: Good to know, and makes it therefore unusable. It's charAt all the way !!