# Operator [ ] and strings ( like charAt() )

Tags: javascript

```
var str = 'foobar';
console.log( str[4] );

prints: 
a
```

This proves that string also acts like an array.Am i correct?

Comment: Define "acts like an array". To what extend does a string need to "act like an array" for that statement to be considered true?

Comment: I don't know about "proof", but String is spec'd to support array-like (read-only) access to the characters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx)

Answer (score 3):

You can't set characters at a specific index, so no, not really:

```
> var a = 'foo';
undefined
> a[0] = 'x';  // No warning, no error. It just silently fails.
"x"
> a
"foo"
```

Comment: +1. And this is also mentioned in the spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String): "For character access using bracket notation, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed."