# if url doesn't end with "/" append "/" to that url using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
if(url.contains(/) at the end of the url){
    //do nothing
}
else if(url.not contains(/) at the end of the url)
    //url must be appended with "/"
}
```

`<a href="www.xyz.com/abc"></a>` this is my piece of code

the url here is `www.xyz.com/abc` but i require it as `www.xyz.com/abc/`

if u notice the new url, it is appended by "/"

Thanks

Comment: do you want to add this to all url present in page/website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = "www.xyz.com/abc";
if(url.slice(-1) != "/"){
   url += "/";
}
```

Demo -->  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Zf3gN/2/

Answer (score 3):

regular expressions

```
if (!str.match("/$")) {
    str += "/";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/olucuf/1/edit)

Comment: you're welcome! and you had also an extra `.` ;) nice example btw, +1'd and thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
par = link.indexOf('/') != -1 ? link : link+"/"
```

Comment: This is not correct. It's about the last character, not any character.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have to check the last character, you can do exactly that:

```
var url = 'http://www.bla.com';
if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) != '/') {
  url += '/';
}
```

Comment: Better to use `url.charAt(url.length - 1)`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = url.lastIndexOf('/') !== (url.length -1) ? url += '/' : url;
```

**[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCsWk/)**

Answer (score 0):

try below for adding / at the end of all the links present on page

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var link = this.href;
    this.href = link.lastIndexOf('/') != (link.length -1)  ? link += '/' : link;
});
```