# What's the easiest way to capitalize letters after dash in a string?

Tags: javascript

I want to transform a string like *config-option* into *configOption*. What will be the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `match[1]`, I'd recommend `match.charAt(1)` (see [string.charAt(x) or string[x]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx)):

```
str.replace(/-./g, function(match) {return match.charAt(1).toUpperCase();})
```

Alternatively, you can use a group in your regex:

```
str.replace(/-(.)/g, function(m, c) {return c.toUpperCase();})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used regular expression and specified the replacement as function not as string.

```
str.replace(/-./g, function(match) {return match[1].toUpperCase();})
```