# AngularJS Custom Filter with Argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

My custom filter should output:

Mark

...however it's outputting:

- M
- a
- r
- k

Here's my view:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | myFriend:currentUser">
        {{ friend }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

...and controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.filter('myFriend', function () {
  return function (items, currentUser) {
    console.log(items);
    console.log(currentUser);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i] === currentUser) {
        return items[i];
      }
    }

  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentUser = 'Mark';
  $scope.friends = ['Andrew', 'Will', 'Mark', 'Alice', 'Todd'];
});
```

Here is my Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JCKAt05MPlrvIZBCGO0n?p=preview

How can my custom filter output "Mark"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I presume you are aware the filter is being applied to the list friends.

Your filter is returning a single string value.

Your ng-repeat can be thought of as:

```
ng-repeat="friend in (friends | myFriend:currentUser)"
```

which means you are trying to loop over the string returned by your myFriend filter.  For the browser you're using ng-repeat over a string loops over each character in the string.

(Note: this might not happen on every browser, because some browsers (e.g. IE7) [do not allow `[]` subscripting on strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943760/528246).  (Underneath it all, ng-repeat would rely on the value having a length property and `[]` subscripting.)

The following may produce the result you want (assuming you only ever want one name to be shown from the list)

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li>
        {{ friends | myFriend:currentUser }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are passing a string from the filter instead of array of string. `ng-repeat` will iterate though the characters (string is an array of chars) of the string `Mark` and display it. You need to instead pass array to `ng-repeat`. Filter is run first before applying source to `ng-repeat`.
Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i] === currentUser) {
    return [items[i]];
  }
}
```

In your specific case you could just as well do as below, without creating any custom filter:

```
 <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:currentUser:true">
  {{ friend }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

My strong suggestion is dont write extra code. Its like reinventing the wheel. Instead stick to the general procedure and filter it out. A small change in your friends array will get you better result with minimal coding. Use angular to minimalize your coding.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{name:currentUser}">
        {{ friend.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentUser = 'Mark';
  $scope.friends = [{'name':'Andrew'}, {'name':'Will'}, {'name':'Mark'}, {'name':'Alice'}, {'name':'Todd'}];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below updated filter. You are returning String whereas you should return an array. Thats why `ng-repeat` is considering that String as an array and iterating every letters.

```
app.filter('myFriend', function () {
    return function (items, currentUser) {
        console.log(items);
        console.log(currentUser);
        var finalItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] === currentUser) {
                finalItems.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return finalItems;
    };
});
```