# Trim trim all letter after the first letter

Tags: javascript, trim

How do I trim all letter after the first letter?

e.g

```
var name = "Tony";
//output T
```

Comment: Clarify "letter". What is the expected output of "1a2b3" ?

Comment: @Thilo he has clearly expressed the expected output in the comment

Comment: @shennan: In that example, all characters happen to be letters (no digits, no interpunctation, no space, etc). That makes it a bit ambiguous, which is why I am asking.

Comment: @Thilo Ah, sorry. Temporary blindness. I didn't see your "la2b3" example. I thought you were just asking "What is the expected output?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not called a trim, this is a simple `substring` :

```
console.log(name.substring(0, 1));
```

As suggested, you can also do

```
console.log(name[0]);
```

But this one will not works on old internet explorers (< IE7). This one will works everywhere too :

```
console.log(name.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Or even simpler, name[0]

Comment: @DrunkWolf I would prefer name.charAt(0), as bracket notation is not supported in some older browsers. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943760/726766).

Comment: @shennan I find it hard to believe some people still concern themselves with IE7, seeing as it has a market share of <0.2%, but fair enough :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf True, but it's also more readable. There is no mistaking `name` for an object or an array. When there's no pain involved, I don't see the problem with supporting older browsers.

Comment: @shennan I wholeheartedly agree that there is no problem supporting older browers, but if the variable name is descriptive enough (like name is) we don't really have the problem with mistaking it for something it clearly isn't. If you regularly name objects or arrays 'name', you should seriously consider naming your variables better. That said, i upvoted your comment, as it's a legitimate consideration to make. I would personally go for name[0] myself, unless there was a chance i would be assigning values to the first character later on.

Comment: @DrunkWolf And I up-voted your original comment before considering it from the angle of browser support and readability. I don't think this needs to be an extended discussion. The benefits of each approach are clear to readers now.