# Why charAt() and charCodeAt() are called safe?

Tags: javascript, string, char, charat

I was learning about javascript string methods [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp).

Under section **Extracting String Characters**, it said:

There are 2 **safe** methods for extracting string characters:

- `charAt(position)`
- `charCodeAt(position)`

The questions here are:

- Why these methods are called **safe**?
- What are these methods protecting from?

Comment: Just below that section is a section named `Accessing a String as an Array is Unsafe`, which explains what they mean.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Yes, I discovered that section after asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to access a character from a string.

```
// Bracket Notation
"Test String1"[6]

// Real Implementation
"Test String1".charAt(6)
```

**It is a bad idea to use brackets, for these reasons ([Source](http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/dangerous-bracket-notation-for-strings.html)):**

> **This notation does not work in IE7.**
>   The first code snippet will return
>   undefined in IE7. If you happen to use
>   the bracket notation for strings all
>   over your code and you want to migrate
>   to `.charAt(pos)`, this is a real pain:
>   Brackets are used all over your code
>   and there's no easy way to detect if
>   that's for a string or an
>   array/object.
>
> **You can't set the character using this notation.** As there is no warning of
>   any kind, this is really confusing and
>   frustrating. If you were using the
>   `.charAt(pos)` function, you would not
>   have been tempted to do it.

Also, it can produce unexpected results in [edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742383/2404470)

```js
console.log('hello' [NaN]) // undefined
console.log('hello'.charAt(NaN)) // 'h'

console.log('hello' [true]) //undefined
console.log('hello'.charAt(true)) // 'e'
```

Basically, it's a short-cut notation that is not fully implemented across all browsers.

Note, you are not able to write characters using either method. However, that functionality is a bit easier to understand with the `.charAt()` function which, in most languages, is a read-only function.

So for the compatibility purpose `.charAt` is considered to be safe.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943760/1496715)

Speed Test: http://jsperf.com/string-charat-vs-bracket-notation

```
Testing in Chrome 47.0.2526.80 on Mac OS X 10.10.4
Test    Ops/sec

String charAt
testCharAt("cat", 1);
117,553,733
±1.25%
fastest

String bracket notation
testBracketNotation("cat", 1);
118,251,955
±1.56%
fastest
```

Comment: Does it mean that [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) guys must edit the wordings from **safe**  to **cross browser compatible** methods? Because these are two different things.

Comment: Not exactly browser compatibility, but `.charAt` can also be used to modify the string, which can not be done using `bracket notations`.

Comment: Bracket string indexing is 2-3 times quicker than `.charAt` which can make a significant difference in the runtime when manipulating large strings. Though attempting to index outside the string's length bracket indexing has woeful performance compared to `.charAt` being over 10 times slower.

Comment: @Blindman67 Two major drawbacks are Bracket notation does not work in IE7.  You can't set the character using this notation. And see this http://jsperf.com/string-charat-vs-bracket-notation, bracket notation is definitely not 2-3 times faster.

Comment: @void I found an [edge case problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30742383/2404470)

Comment: @student The charAt function depends on how the index is converted to a Number

Comment: @void my tests show different results. Though I am using large strings 1MB+