# How do I remove part of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that works like

`"aaaabbccccdeeeaaaaa"` --> `"abcdea"`

but I can't figure out how to actually remove characters from the string. So where I'm at is

```
String.prototype.removeConsecutives = function()
{
      let k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.length; ++i)
        if(this[i] !== this[i-1])
          this[k++] = this[i];
    // now I want to remove the characters in the range
    // of indices [k, this.length)
}
```

Comment: Two things: don't modify built-in properties (you might touch something you didn't know was there), and don't try to modify a string in place (it won't work).

Comment: `"aaaabbccccdeeeaaaaa".replace(/([a-z])\1+/gi,'$1')`

Comment: You shoul use charAt(i) instead of[i]. A regex is a better option.

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan what is the benefit of using `charAt` over `[]`?

Comment: @zerkms: Works in pre-ES5 browsers…

Comment: @zerkms, substring, substr or charAt are the only ways in JS to refer to a character in string

Comment: @Bergi not sure if it is a joke or not, hmmmm

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan surely, `[]` is a way to access a character in JS

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan - You forgot `.slice()`. And `.split("")[i]`.

Comment: @zerkms: I mean [it *was* a benefit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5943726/1048572) back in the days when IE7 was relevant :-)

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with a regex replace:

```js
var result = "aaaabbccccdeeeaaaaa".replace(/(.)\1+/g,"$1");

console.log(result);
```

In the regex I've shown, `(.)` matches any character, and then `\1` is a back-reference to whatever matched in the parentheses with `+` meaning one or more of those. Do a global replace with the `g` flag. And the replacement string uses `$1` to use the sub-match in parentheses.