# Doubling each letter in a String in js

Tags: javascript

I need string Double each letter in a string

> abc -> aabbcc

i try this

```
var s = "abc";
for(var i = 0; i < s.length  ; i++){
   console.log(s+s);
}
```

o/p

```
>     abcabc    
>     abcabc  
>     abcabc
```

but i need

> aabbcc

help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) , [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods.

```js
var s = "abc";

console.log(
  // split the string into individual char array
  s.split('').map(function(v) {
    // iterate and update
    return v + v;
    // join the updated array
  }).join('')
)
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can even use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method for that.

```js
var s = "abc";

console.log(
  // replace each charcter with repetition of it
  // inside substituting string you can use $& for getting matched char
  s.replace(/./g, '$&$&')
)
```

Comment: s.replace(/./g, '$&$&')  --way cooler than the rest.  Very elegant.  Although using the For loop probably more efficient, if there is a lot of input involved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the specific character at the index within the string with `s[i]` rather than just `s` itself.

```
var s = "abc";
var out = "";
for(var i = 0; i < s.length  ; i++){
   out = out + (s[i] + s[i]);
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: A useful reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx

Answer (score 2):

I have created a function which takes string as an input and iterate the string and returns the final string with each character doubled.

```js
var s = "abcdef";

function makeDoubles(s){

  var s1 = "";
  for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    s1 += s[i]+s[i];
  }
  return s1;
  
}

alert(makeDoubles(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make it  with a loop, then you have to  print  s[i]+s[i];
not, s + s.

```
var s = "abc";
let newS = "";
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  newS += s[i] + s[i];
}

console.log(newS);
```

that works for me, maybe a little bit hardcoded, but I am new too))
good luck

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(s+s);`, here `s` holds entire string. You will have to fetch individual character and append it.

```js
var s = "abc";
var r = ""
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var c = s.charAt(i);
  r+= c+c
}

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var doubleStr = function(str) {
    str = str.split('');
    var i = 0;

    while (i < str.length) {
        str.splice(i, 0, str[i]);
        i += 2;
    }

    return str.join('');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We loop through the characters of the input, duplicating it and appending it to an output that was initialized as an empty string.

```
function doubleChar(str) {
  let s = str;
  let s1 = "";
  let result = "";
  
  for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    s1 = s[i] + s[i];
    result += s1;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(doubleChar("abc"));
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by combining `split`, `join` and template literals:

```js
function output(value) {
    return value.split("").map(item => `${item}${item}`).join('');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="console.log(output(this.value))">
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic function to repeat all characters in a string [n] times, using [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). Check browser availability of `String.repeat` [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=string%3A%20repeat).

```js
const repeatChars = (str, n = 2) => str.replace(/./g, v => v.repeat(n));
const repeatLetters = (str, n = 2) => str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, v => v.repeat(n));
const str = `abc d e`;
console.log(repeatChars(str));
console.log(repeatChars(str, 5));
console.log(repeatLetters(str, 2));

// when String.prototype.repeat is not available use:
function strRepeat(str, n = 2) {
  return [...Array(n)].map(_ => str).join(``);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use one of these two methods:

```
const doubleChar = (str) => str.split("").map(c => c + c).join("");
```

**OR**

```
function doubleChar(str) {
    var word = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    word = word + str[i] + str[i];
  };
  return word;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for try to help, but this answer is the same than others answers.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function doubleChar(str) {
  
  let sum = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    
   let result = (str[i]+str[i]);
   
   sum = sum + result;

  }
  
   return sum;

}

console.log (doubleChar ("Hello"));
```