# Lodash -- array methods on strings

Tags: lodash

I have found that in lodash, the array methods also work on strings. For example:

```
> _.last('abc')
'c'

> _.indexOf('abc', 'x')
-1
```

Is this a standard behavior, and **can this be relied on**? The documentation does not say anything about it as far as I know.

Please note that the above methods are just examples. What I am more inclined to know is whether lodash expects its array methods to be used on strings. I need to write production code and I can not rely on something that works but the standard docs have not mentioned or acknowledged or guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider a [String](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) to essentially be an array of characters. They have certain properties and functions that you'd find on an Array, such as `.length` and `.indexOf()`.

Based on the lodash source for [*.last*](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.2/lodash.js#L7611-L7614) and [.indexOf](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.2/lodash.js#L7452-L7462), they use the `.length` property to determine the last character, or index of a character within an array.

These implementations, while could work with Strings in most scenarios because of their Array-like nature, will not work in all, since lodash uses bracket notation (`str[0]`) to find the last character/index of an item with an array. This is [not universally supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx) e.g. for IE7, which is why the `charAt` method exists for accessing a character at a given index for a string.

You can do both of these things natively:

```
var str = 'mystring';
str.charAt(str.length - 1); // 'g'

var str = 'mystring';
str.indexOf('y') // 1`
```