# When reversing string, I'm getting a NaN at the end. Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string, and it does work, but when I store the userInput[i] into the result variable, I'm getting NaN at the end of the string.

```
//variables
var userInput, result;

userInput = prompt("Enter a string that you want reversed: ");

for (var i = userInput.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += userInput[i];
}

console.log("Your string: \n" + result);
```

Comment: index starts from 0

Comment: `undefined + undefined` is `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start the loop from `userInput.length` which is a wrong index because `userInput[userInput.length]` is `undefined`. What you need to do is start from `userInput.length - 1` like this (and don't forget to initialize `result` to empty string before starting to accumulate the result):

```
result = "";
for (var i = userInput.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  result += userInput[i];
}
```

**NOTE:** When going up an array, we don't actually reach the point when we access the `userInput.length` index (**i.e.** `userInput[userInput.length]`) because usually the condition for the loop is `i < userInput.length` which fail as soon as `i` is equal to `userInput.length`. When going downwards an array, one should keep track of what are the indexes allowed.

**NOTE 2:** It is safer to use `string.charAt(index)` rather than `string[index]`. Learn why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx).

Comment: this is the only correct answer so far, but it would be better you if explain what have you changed and why

Comment: 1) declare result variable as default string
2) in for loop "userInput.length - 1"  Coz. array first index is 0.

Comment: Why do you declare `var result` twice?

Comment: coz,  Initialize it to be an empty string so JavaScript knows it should handle it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off, by reversing a string in JavaScript using something like below:

```
'YOURSTRING'.split('').reverse().join('');
```

e-g

> 'abcdef'.split('').reverse().join('')  will give you fedcba

Comment: Best way to do this (Y).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
    var userInput, result = ""; // initialize this first
    
    userInput = prompt("Enter a string that you want reversed: ");
    
    for (var i = userInput.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      result += userInput[i];
    }
    console.log("Your string: \n" + result);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: @Ameya initialise the result variable `var result = ""` , unless it'll append `undefined` first.

Comment: @Pavlo it is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

this problem consists of 2 smaller problems.

**First problem:**

"result" is not initialized so it contains "undefined" which messes with the string later on. Initialize it to be an empty string so JavaScript knows it should handle it as a string since the "+"-operator is overloaded to handle addition and string concatenation.

**Second problem**

The index of the userInput string reaches from 0 - (userInput.length - 1), so change the loop accordingly.

```
var userInput, result = ""; // initialize this first

userInput = prompt("Enter a string that you want reversed: ");

// initialize i with (userInput.length - 1) since the index ends there
for (var i = userInput.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  result += userInput[i];
}
console.log("Your string: \n" + result);
```

Comment: Nice explanation. A code sample will make it even better.

Answer (score 1):

The `length` property of `String` returns the letters' count whereas the index of an `Array` starts from 0. So, your issue could be resolved by reducing the string length by 1 i.e. `userInput.length - 1`.

```
var userInput, result="";

userInput = prompt("Enter a string that you want reversed: ");

for (var i = userInput.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  result += userInput[i];
}
console.log("Your string: \n" + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get you string.`Split` it into array.`reverse` your array and `join`.Finally you will get the reversed string.

```js
 var userInput, result = ""; // initialize this first
    
    userInput = prompt("Enter a string that you want reversed: ");
    
   result = userInput.split("").reverse().join("");
    console.log("Reversed string: \n" + result);
```