# how to change single parts of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to accomplish the following:

```
var a = "hello"
var b 
b[0]=a[0]
```

so that

```
  b[0] 
 >"h"
```

the first letter of b should be the same as the first letter of a so I want to assign a[0] (which is h) to b[0]. I don't want to be restricted to the first letter, I want to use it to do things like

```
for(var i = 0; i<a; i++){
if( a.match(/[a-z]/i) !==null ){b[i] = " "}
else{b[i] = a[i]}
```

(replacing all the non-letters with spaces.) (this is just an example since I've been asked to clarify the question)

Comment: Can you post some example on sample input and output

Comment: what you really want to achieve, your question points to empty

Comment: SO is not to teach you looping and things. Show us your work and ask questions on blockers.

Comment: i want to change a[0] to be the same as b[0] but I can't modify single parts of a string

Answer (score 4):

You could desturct the string and take an object for changing a letter at a certain position and join it back to a string. Then assign it to the variable.

```js
var a = "hello",
    b = "foo";

b = Object.assign([...b], { 0: a[0] }).join('');

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Any reason you chose `a[0]` instead of `a.charAt(0)`?

Comment: @Chris, it is shorter and it features the same rule as all iterative objects with an index.

Comment: Reading from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx I guess it's only a matter of taste