# Javascript String.charAt(i) and string[i] give a different result?

Tags: javascript, string

I wrote a short function to split a string into an array of words (using a loop -- this was an exercise, I don't claim it's pretty code).  It works fine when I use `String.charAt()` to access a character but doesn't when I use `string[i]`.  Shouldn't these give the same results?

```
"use strict"

function whitespace(ch) {
   return (ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t') || (ch == '\n');
}

function splitToWords(string) {
  var words = [];
  var wordStart = 0;
  var inWord = false;
  var isWhitespace;

  for (var i = 0; i <= string.length; i++) {
 //this works fine
    isWhitespace = whitespace(string.charAt(i));
 // but this doesn't -- causes the final test (below) to fail
   // isWhitespace = whitespace(string[i]);
    if (inWord && isWhitespace) {
      words.push(string.slice(wordStart, i));
      inWord = false;
    } else if (!inWord && !isWhitespace) {
      wordStart = i;
      inWord = true;
    }
  }
  if (inWord) words.push(string.slice(wordStart, i));
  return words;
}
```

This test passes when I use `String.charAt()` but fails using index access to the string

```
var words = splitToWords('      ');

console.log(words.length === 0); // => true
```

Shouldn't the two modes of access give the same result?  Thanks for any help in pointing out my error!

Comment: It works exactly the same. Your code in fact executes exactly the same for me with `string[i]`.

Comment: This could be a browser difference, technically you should not use the array version. Also please name the variable! string[1] should return 't' This may be of help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx

Comment: They work the same for me. Check the output here: http://rextester.com/SPYPQ47289

Comment: Thanks to all.  I was running it in Node REPL.  I'll check it in a browser.  And thanks for the suggestions.  I actually had read that StackOverflow article but had thought perhaps it was OK to use the array form now, as it is part of ECMA 5.