# what's difference between my code or other?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why both these codes work well.

1. `if ( str.charAt(i) === char )`  < this is my code
2. `if ( str[i] === char )`  << this is others

could you tell me why str[i] works well?

Question:

### Write a function called "countCharacter".

Given a string input and a character, "countCharacter" returns the number of occurrences of a given character in the given string.

Ex:

```
let output = countCharacter('I am a hacker', 'a');
console.log(output); // --> 3
```

This is mine:

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
  // your code here
  let countRet = 0;
  for ( let i = 0; i < str.length; i = i + 1 ) { 
    if ( str.charAt(i) === char ) {  // <<< here
      countRet = countRet + 1 ;
    }
  }
  return countRet;
}

countCharacter("hello", "l" );
```

This is from other:

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
  // your code here
  let countRet = 0;
  for ( let i = 0; i < str.length; i = i + 1 ) {
    if ( str[i] === char ) {  //<<<< here
      countRet = countRet + 1 ;
    }
  }
  return countRet;
}

countCharacter("hello", "l" );
```

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation on `String` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access. That should answer your question

Comment: You need to check before posting question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx

Answer (score 0):

It is introduced in ES5: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es5.asp

> ECMAScript 5 Syntactical Changes
>
> - Property access [ ] on strings