# capitalizing first characters in an array using for loops inside arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arrow-functions

The goal was to get the first letters of the items in the array to be capitalized but it's printing out undefined

```js
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
const singularWords = words.map(w => w.slice(0, -1))
// The below line should console.log: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
console.log(singularWords);

// Bonus:
const capitalizedWords = words.map((w) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  }
});
// The below line should console.log: ["Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles"]
console.log(capitalizedWords);
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from `.map`. You are mutating `words` instead. Try `words.map((word) => ( word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1) ))`

Comment: Als why map words and then loop too?

Comment: beautiful, thank you so much!, I'm still having problems understanding this but hopefully, I'll get better

Answer (score 3):

You map AND loop

Just map, and use slice again

PS: [a discussion of w[0] vs w.charAt(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943807/295783)

```js
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
const singularWords = words.map(w => w.slice(0, -1))
// The below line should console.log: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
console.log(singularWords);

// Bonus:
const capitalizedWords = words.map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+w.slice(1));
// The below line should console.log: ["Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles"]
console.log(capitalizedWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an alternate approach signifying use of desctructuring pattern.

#### Idea

- In the arrow function, use a destructuring pattern for first argument
- Have 2 variables:

  - `firstChar`: holding the first character and this will be used for upperCase.
  - `rest`: The rest of characters. However, since we are using spread operator, it'll be an array and we will have to use `.join('')` for it.

```js
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
const singularWords = words.map(([ firstChar ]) => firstChar )
// The below line should console.log: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
console.log(singularWords);

// Bonus:
const capitalizedWords = words.map(( [ firstChar, ...rest ] ) => firstChar.toUpperCase() + rest.join('') );
// The below line should console.log: ["Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles"]
console.log(capitalizedWords);
```

---

If you wish this formatting for representation, using CSS would be better:

```js
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
const div = document.querySelector('.content');
words.forEach((word) => {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.classList.add('title-case');
  p.innerText = word;
  div.append(p);
})
```

```css
.title-case {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function - `map()` is basically looping for you.

```
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
const singularWords = words.map(w => w.slice(0,-1))
// The below line should console.log: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
console.log(singularWords);

// Bonus:
const capitalizedWords = words.map((w) => {
  return w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
});
// The below line should console.log: ["Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles"]
console.log(capitalizedWords);
```

Here is the correct code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No need for this: `,w.length`. `.substr(1)` should be more than enough

Comment: No need for the return either - see my answer

Comment: @mplungjan you both answered 3 seconds apart. This will happen for simple questions

Answer (score 0):

```
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
const singularWords = words.map(w => w.slice(0, -1))
// The below line should console.log: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
console.log(singularWords);

// Bonus:
const capitalizedWords = words.map(w => w[0].toUpperCase()+w.slice(1));
// The below line should console.log: ["Planes", "Trains", "Automobiles"]
console.log(capitalizedWords);
```

Use only map . You can dele charAt , and add w[0]